# How to track error in android studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio

I simply added line :
"AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();"
in oncreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_list);



    // Install the application crash handler.  This is only done on the first activity.
    ApplicationCrashHandler.installHandler();

    // Work out if we are in 2-pane (tablet) mode or not
    mTwoPane = (findViewById(R.id.note_detail_container) != null);

    // Initialize the Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

    // Initialize the floating action button
    addNoteButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addNoteButton);
    addNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {"
```

How i can track and fix next errors?

In logcat:

> 02-08 10:48:49.501 19023-19023/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes, PID: 19023
>                                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/amazonaws/mobile/auth/userpools/CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider;
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.registerConfigSignInProviders(AWSMobileClient.java:318)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.fetchCognitoIdentity(AWSMobileClient.java:277)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.initializeWithBuilder(AWSMobileClient.java:183)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.access$100(AWSMobileClient.java:72)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$InitializeBuilder.execute(AWSMobileClient.java:429)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.mynotes.NoteListActivity.onCreate(NoteListActivity.java:88)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6314)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.userpools.CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                           at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.registerConfigSignInProviders(AWSMobileClient.java:318) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.fetchCognitoIdentity(AWSMobileClient.java:277) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.initializeWithBuilder(AWSMobileClient.java:183) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.access$100(AWSMobileClient.java:72) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$InitializeBuilder.execute(AWSMobileClient.java:429) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.mynotes.NoteListActivity.onCreate(NoteListActivity.java:88) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6314) 
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
>                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.userpools.CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                 ... 19 more
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: What are you asking about? What is the code that caused this? In what circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

go to Run>Toggle Line Breakpoint to all lines that could throw an exception or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
Then Run>Debug 'yourAppName' or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

> > I'd personally put them:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute(); // here

setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_list); // here



// Install the application crash handler.  This is only done on the first activity.
ApplicationCrashHandler.installHandler(); // here

// Work out if we are in 2-pane (tablet) mode or not
mTwoPane = (findViewById(R.id.note_detail_container) != null); // here

// Initialize the Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

// Initialize the floating action button
addNoteButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addNoteButton);
addNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {" // here
```